# Why is Shem known by the name Malchai-Tzedek?

Tags: parashat-bereishit, genesis-bereishith

Malchai Tzedek was also Shem, son of Noach according to [Targum Yonatan](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.14.18?lang=bi&with=Targum%20Jonathan%20on%20Genesis&lang2=en) and [Targum Yerushalmi](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.14.18?lang=bi&with=Targum%20Jerusalem&lang2=en) to Bereishis 14:18–20 and Talmud Bavli to [Nedarim 32b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.14.18?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Nedarim.32b&lang2=bi).
Why give him two names? It seems confusing for no reason.

Comment: Lots of historical figures throughout Tanach had multiple names

Comment: Hi Castle and welcome to Mi Yodeya! I added links to your sources.

Answer (score 6):

[Rashbam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashbam) in his commentary to Genesis 41:10 lists various names of biblical figures that are not actually the person's given name, but the name that all kings of that place are called by:

> כל פרעה בלשון מצרים מלך וכן כל מלכי מצרים נקראים ושל פלשתים אבימלך אפילו בימי דוד בשנותו את טעמו לפני אבימלך ושל ירושלים מלכי צדק ביהושוע אדני צדק מלך ירושלם ובימי דודעל דברתי אני מבטיח שתהיה מלכי צדק מלך ירושלים ושל עמלק אגג בימי משה וירום מאגג מלכו ובימי שאול אגג מלך עמלק

- Pharaoh – king of Egypt
- Avimelech – king of Philistia
- **Malki Tzedek - king of Jerusalem**
- Agag - King of Amalek

Comment: See also Ralbag to Bereishit 14:18 (and as such a scholar of Ralbag, I'm surprised you missed it):  ומלכי־צדק מלך שלם – הנה היה המנהג לקרוא מלך ירושלם ׳מלכי־צדק׳ או ׳אדוני־צדק׳ כי הכל אחד, כמו שהיה המנהג לקרוא מלך מצרים ׳פרעה׳, ולכן תראה ביהושע (י, א) שהיה שֵׁם מלך ירושלם ׳אדוני־צדק׳. והנה שלם הוא ירושלם, כטעם ׳ויהי בשלם סוּכּוֹ׳ (תהלים עו, ג). והנה אמרו רבותינו ז״ל שזה המלך היה שֵׁם בן נח, ונכון הוא, כי כבר נמצא בדבריו מהשלמוּת הרבה.

Comment: And others, like Radak, Ramban, seem to make similar statements.

Comment: @רבותמחשבות I am flattered by your confidence in my Ralbag scholarship. Indeed I have that line underlined in my copy. When I wrote this answer I remembered that several rishonim say something like this. I knew Rashbam, and in my Rashbam I had noted to cross reference Ibn Ezra (who mentions it regarding Pharaoh but not Malki Tzedek), but I didn’t have a chance then to check my other books.